# Animation not playing anymore

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes, dopesheet

I finished making my animation and I went to change the position of my camera. So I put it in walk navigation and changed the position of my camera. But when I went back into pose mode to play the animation again it wouldn't play. But the keyframes are still there on the dope sheet. Please help

Comment: @moonboots No I havent

Comment: it is not clear what kind of animation you are talking about, are you talking about a camera animation? but you are talking about pose mode, which is for armature...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.